# E_PARSE: syntax error, unexpected ''sidebar_bann' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE), expecting ']' when working with MongoDB ODM and ZF2

Tags: php, mongodb, doctrine-orm

I'm working with ZF2 with Mongo DB and Doctrine-2 ORM, I got the above mentioned error(syntax error, unexpected ''sidebar_bann' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE), expecting ']') on newrelic(newrelic is continuously checking the live environment and logging the errors).I got the following error

Timestamp: 02/26/14 10:49:15

Exception Class: E_PARSE

Error Action: /index.php

Uri: /blog

Error message
E_PARSE: syntax error, unexpected ''sidebar_bann' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE), expecting ']'

I', calling a function from controller(BlogController.php (116)), the function is getUserIdByDomain($domain) which was written on BlogCustomization.php (552)

The parameter of getUserIdByDomain() should always be a sub domain, eg: prodtest-05.xxx.com. It should be always a string value not an array as I'm receiving the value from $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']. The code is as follows,

In Controller

```
$hostname = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
$result = $model->getUserIdByDomain($hostname);
```

In Model

```
public function getUserIdByDomain($domain) {
    $dm = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('doctrine.documentmanager.odm_default');
    $blog_query = $dm->createQueryBuilder('Blog\Document\Blog')
                            ->field('subdomain')->equals($domain);
    $blog_query = $blog_query->getQuery();
    $blog = $blog_query->getSingleResult();
    if (null != $blog) {
            return (int) $blog->getUserId();
    } else {
        $domain_query = $dm->createQueryBuilder('Blog\Document\Blog')
                            ->field('domain.name')->equals($domain);
        $domain_query = $domain_query->getQuery();
        $domain_details = $domain_query->getSingleResult();
    if (null != $domain_details) {
        return (int) $domain_details->getUserId();
    } else {
        //try to get user id in another way
    }
}
```

Context

When user loads their blog (Eg: test-05.example.com), the code catches the host name($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']) from controller and check in the db that is there any blog exist with such a host/sub domain. if yes it will return the user id to get blog post under that user to display in their public blog.

The error appears when I try to fetch data from db with respect to the host(Eg: where subdomain=test-05.example.com) using Doctrine ODM. One of the answer I received about this is as follows

[syntax error, unexpected ''sidebar_bann' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE), expecting ']' when working with MongoDB ODM and ZF2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22813634/syntax-error-unexpected-sidebar-bann-t-encapsed-and-whitespace-expecting)

```
You have a simple php syntax error somewhere. Probably look for something that's an array and key value within a regular string like so

echo '$arrayVar['keyname']';

those single quotes will get you every time if you're not careful.
```

But I haven't used anything like above.

The error points to the this ($blog = $blog_query->getSingleResult()) line. Could anyone please light me something more on this?

Comment: This is rather hard to read, I don't think we need the stack trace. Which line exactly is the error pointing to?

Comment: Edited it by removing the stack trace, could you please specify if the question is not clear for you

Comment: Which line exactly does the error refer to? (Specify in your question please).

Comment: Whats the line after the getSingleResult() line?

Maybe pastebin the entire file if possible, at least a littlebit more context

Comment: added more details as requested

Comment: any help from anyone?